# Repeat the task using while loop until user clicks on “No” button?

Tags: vb.net

```vb
Public Class Form2
    Dim ss As Boolean

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim i, z As Integer
        ss = False
        Butn_no.Focus()

        While ss = False
            Application.DoEvents()
            i = Val(InputBox("enter 1st number", "program#3"
                             ))
            z = Val(InputBox("enter 2nd number", "program#3"))
            If z = 0 Or i = 0 Then
                MsgBox("one of the given number is empty try again or not integer", vbCritical, "error")
            Else
                If z = i * i Then
                    MsgBox("second number is the sqaure of first number", vbInformation, "program#3")
                Else
                    MsgBox("second number is not the square of first" & vbNewLine & " first number = " & i.ToString & " 2nd number = " & z.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "program#3")
                End If
            End If
        End While

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Butn_no.Click
        ss = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

This is working but next time when while executed I am unable to click on button 2 due to input box which is showing at the top, with this same method I stopped the loop which is appending text in textbox in my earlier program. I just want to stop loop execution on button pressed if anyone?

Comment: Instead, use `OkCancel` message box to show the message and to exit the loop if the user clicks the cancel button. You won't be able to click that `button2` because  the loop will continue forever once the modal dialogs are closed.

Comment: This is not a Console application. Remove the loop and show a message (or use the [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) class) when the data entered is not validated. `Button2` is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Val returns a double and you have declared i as an integer. Same problem with z. `Val` is an old VB6 method. .Net has new methods to replace it. I used `Integer.TryParse`. If an non integer is entered it will not update the output variable which will remain 0. If the input is a valid Integer, `i` and `z` will be assigned the new value.

The `Continue While` takes the execution back to the top of the `While`.

Put your exit question in the loop. You can use `Return` to exit the Sub.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim i, z As Integer
    While True
        Integer.TryParse(InputBox("enter 1st number", "program#3"), i)
        Integer.TryParse(InputBox("enter 2nd number", "program#3"), z)
        If z = 0 Or i = 0 Then
            MsgBox("one of the given number is empty try again or not integer", vbCritical, "error")
            Continue While
        Else
            If z = i * i Then
                MsgBox("second number is the sqaure of first number", vbInformation, "program#3")
            Else
                MsgBox("second number is not the square of first" & vbNewLine & " first number = " & i.ToString & " 2nd number = " & z.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, "program#3")
            End If
        End If
        Dim Answer = DialogResult.Yes
        If Answer = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to quit?", "Quit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) Then
            Return
        End If
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks bro. but i made little change because i was assigned that until i press no as program quit on no thanks for ur time .If Answer = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to run it again?", "continue?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) Then
           else
return

        End If